# Laravel Nova - Show/Hide form fields based on a parent Select field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to Show/Hide form fields based on a parent Select field.

For example, I need to show Pen name text field when pen is selected and show Pencil name text field when pencil is selected.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got a Nova package for this feature:

https://novapackages.com/packages/epartment/nova-dependency-container

Comment: This package didn't work for me, and others have reported issues with it, too: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/355

Comment: I don't think this is maintained and current package is very limited.

Comment: The dependency container package does work with the latest nova (currently 2.4) and Laravel (currently 6.1) and is maintained by me since a few weeks now. You should have no problems implementing this with its current version.

Comment: Hi, I moved this package to nova 4:
https://github.com/alexwenzel/nova-dependency-container